# .htaccess mod-rewrite question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

hey there, i have quite some issues with the mode rewrite here is what i use :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /creatii.php?creatie_thumb=$2&user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /creatiiuser.php?user=$1
```

i would like this link :

```
http://creatii.artcrew.ro/creatii.php?creatie_thumb=creatie19&user=dee-dee
```

to look:

```
like http://creatii.artcrew.ro/dee-dee/creatie19
```

***well this is fine, it works, no problems with it but i want to make a rule for another link***

```
http://creatii.artcrew.ro/categorii.php?numecat=poetry&numesubcat=satire
```

***to look like***

```
http://creatii.artcrew.ro/poetry/satire
```

how can i do this? what rules must i use?

currently if i access http://creatii.artcrew.ro/poetry/satire 
it access the link : http://creatii.artcrew.ro/creatii.php?creatie_thumb=satire&user=poetry

how can i make both links(the first one and the second one) work?

one more thing, i want this link : http://creatii.artcrew.ro/creatiiuser.php?user=Dan to look like  http://creatii.artcrew.ro/Dan or if that does not work http://creatii.artcrew.ro/user/Dan
how can i do that?

can anyone help me?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the URL `http://creatii.artcrew.ro/X/Y`, how is mod_rewrite supposed to know whether `X` and `Y` are `creatie_thumb` and `user` values or `numecat` and `numesubcat` values?

You need to add something to the URL to differentiate these cases.

For example:

- `http://creatii.artcrew.ro/user/dee-dee`
- `http://creatii.artcrew.ro/user/dee-dee/creatie19`
- `http://creatii.artcrew.ro/cat/poetry/satire`

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /creatii.php?creatie_thumb=$2&user=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/$ /creatiiuser.php?user=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^cat/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /creatii.php?numecat=$1&numesubcat=$2 [L]
```

Comment: meh yeah this is right but can`t i do this for only one category? just one without any maping? and the rest with maping?

Comment: Yes, you could have one type of mapping not require any special token on the URL.  You'd need to make sure it was the first RewriteRule, and it would break if there was a possible value that matched the tokens you use (e.g. a username of "cat").

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're too much generic with your rules and you got conflicts.

Try to map this urls

http://creatii.artcrew.ro/creatii/dee-dee/creatie1
http://creatii.artcrew.ro/categorii/poetry/satire

Starting from those sample you can easily map your urls with no conflict on rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^creaati/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /creatii.php?creatie_thumb=$2&user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^categorii/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /categorii.php?numecat=$1&numesubcat=$2 [L]
```

Do some tries :D

Comment: yes that would work, but i created the subdomani especialy for some creations if i use : http://creatii.artcrew.ro/creatii/ that subdomain would have no sense isen`t there another way to at least show the first url just like this : http://creatii.artcrew.ro/dee-dee/creatie19 ? and the rest with maping